# I always hit the wrong reply-button

Tags: google-groups

If I want to reply to a particular mail, I always hit the wrong button in the web app Google Groups.

In this case I want to reply to "Antonis Christofides".

[image: screen shot]

Is there a way to display the reply-button below the mail instead of above? ... or an other solution?